# How to read the browser addressbar in ubuntu using python?

Tags: python, firefox, google-chrome, chromium, automation

I'm looking for a library that can fetch me the content of the browser address bar in Ubuntu. I have used the UIAutomation library in windows that worked fine by getting me the content of the browser address bar after some coding.

Is there any library that can do so or if not, please let me know how to do the same without any library usage in python? I need an idea of how to get the content of address-bar of browsers Chromium, google chrome and Firefox in Ubuntu (I'm using 20.04)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, how about full automation like Selenium. https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/browser_manipulation/ or another alternative https://alternativeto.net/software/selenium/ . I don't know much about this topic.

Comment: Selenium browser manipulation can be done in the browser which is started by selenium. I cannot able to connect the selenium tool to the already open browser.I need not want to manipulate complete browser actions. I just need to read the address bar of the browser tabs that is active.